# Create a DLL Delphi, which exports C++ Classes

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

for a plugin I need to create a DLL which exports C++ classes. (for Siemens HMI Operate) My problem is, that I want to write this plugin in Delphi. I need to use a lot of my own libs which are all Delphi.

So the question is: Can such a DLL be created with Delphi?

When I open such a plugin DLL (written in Visual C++) in PE Explorer it exports look like this:

```
?createDialogBar@SlGfwPluginByMakroBase@@UAEPAVSlGfwDialogBar@@ABVQString@@PAVQWidget@@0@Z

public: virtual class SlGfwDialogBar * __thiscall SlGfwPluginByMakroBase::createDialogBar(class QString const &,class QWidget *,class QString const &)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can such a DLL be created with Delphi?

No it cannot. You'll need to create the DLL using the specific C++ implementation that the host process expects.

Perhaps the best you can do is to create the plugin DLL in that specific C++ implementation, and then implement the methods of the class by calling into your Delphi code. But the C++ class that is imported by the host process must be implemented using C++. In other words you use C++ to make a bridge between the plugin interface which mandates a specific C++ implementation, and your code which is written in Delphi.

Comment: This means there is no standard C++ DLL it always depends on the C++ compiler. So for example there is a Visual C++ 2008 DLL. Is this correct?

Comment: That's right. C++ classes are not suitable for binary interop. This is why COM exists. Whoever designed this plugin interface did not think it through, in my view.